# Magento getFinalPrice no working with customer group discounts

Tags: php, magento

I have the following simple code with a loop of products:

```
$_product->setCustomerGroupId(6);   
$price = $_product->getFinalPrice();
```

I have a customer group (id of 6) that has a 50% discount applied to it.

The $price variable is always the full price. How can I get the discounted price?

This is in an API script I am writing, so there is no customer/session object. I can create one if required but would prefer to try and steer clear of creating temp sessions.

Comment: Could you find a way to solve this in the meantime? Having the same problem now...

Answer (score 0):

Check This:

```
<?php 
  $now = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->timestamp(time());
  $websiteId = 1;
  $customerGroup = 4;
  $productId = 9369;
  $rules = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule');
  $rules->getRulePrice($now, $websiteId, $customerGroup, $productId));
?>
```